# Have you asked a question only to find out you were the one to answer it?

Tags: discussion

Have you ever started asking a question on SO and then find out that someone had already asked it. And the person who answered it was you? I seem to find myself doing this fairly often.

Comment: Let me see if I follow you... So, someone asked a question, you answered it, then you reasked the same question later?

Comment: Grasshopper! You must practice your search-fu, if you are ever to be a master.

Comment: That's what I call a memory loss

Comment: This, ladies and gentlemen, is when you know you have a drug problem. ;)

Comment: He's got an *addiction*, not a problem

Answer (score 5):

I had the inverse happen (not to me) once: I saw a question that I remembered being asked a while ago, but could only remember the kludgy solution, so I decided to post it just to bump the question up in the hopes that a greater CPAN guru would post a better answer. As I was posting it in flew said guru who ended up posting two different and superior answers. Turns out he only knew the answer because he had asked the exact same question, which was the question I remembered not remembering the answer to.

So in the end, that's really nothing like what you were asking about. No, I haven't. Sorry.

Comment: I love English!

Comment: I love twisted intertwined story time frames

Comment: I love pie! Mmmmm <3

Answer (score 2):

No.  But I have read an answer, thinking "that's a great answer", only to realize later that I wrote it.  So far I haven't seen one of mine where I thought "wow, that's crappy" -- though I have edited a few to make them even better.  :-)

The crappy ones usually get discarded before submission or shortly thereafter.